# php iconv from utf-8 to windows-1252 not working if string contains ñ

Tags: php, utf-8, iconv, windows-1252

If I have a string encoded with utf-8 that contains the character ñ:

```
$str = "A Coruña";
```

a `mb_detect_encoding($str)` displays it is encoded with UTF-8.

and I use the following code:

```
$recoded = iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1252", $str);
```

I get an empty string in `$recoded`, and a `mb_detect_encoding($recoded)` shows that is encoded with ASCII

`iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1252//TRANSLIT", $str)` also returns an empty string.

`iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1252//IGNORE", $str)` returns a string with 'A Coru�a' and a `mb_detect_encoding($recoded)` shows that is encoded with UTF-8

I can't find a way to encode $str with windows-1252 and gives the original text even when it contains the character ñ (and some other characters as vowels with ´ ).

Is there another way to do the format conversion properly in PHP 5.6?

I'm using PHP version 5.6.33

Comment: Hmm… https://3v4l.org/FiKn4

Comment: Try [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/bin2hex) on those strings to get an idea of the *actual* encoding?

Comment: bin2hex returns:
´434c494331093131353133094d6172696120476f796f616761094343204d6172696e65646120436974792e204c6f63616c20312e383320437472612f204261c3b16f73206465204172746569786f2c203433093135303038094120436f7275c3b161094120436f7275d18161094553096d61726961676f796f61676131313140676d61696c2e636f6d0909590935343635343635343633340a0a´. 

Is there another way to do the format conversion in PHP 5.6?

Comment: From the PHP manual: “Caution: If and how //TRANSLIT works exactly depends on the system's iconv() implementation (cf. ICONV_IMPL). Some implementations are known to ignore //TRANSLIT, so the conversion is likely to fail for characters which are illegal for the out_charset.” http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: This does work on my system (Ubuntu 14.04), when I try to convert it into ASCII. Could it be, that WINDOWS-1252 is unknown to the underlying host system?

Comment: It is perfectly possible, as I'm running this project in localhost, with an operating system OSX High Sierra